# How to get Camera2 preview frame as Bitmap or OpenCV Mat with renderscript

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera2, renderscript, yuv

I want to do real time image processing with OpenCV and I want to use the Android Camera2 API. My problem is converting the preview frame to an OpenCV Mat (or at first to a bitmap would help too).

I know you can attach an ImageReader to the camera and convert every available Image to a Bitmap. The problem is that attaching an ImageReader to the camera reduces the framerate drastically (not any image conversion, but just using the ImageReader without any additional code).
So my idea was to attache the surface of an Allocation to the camera, pass that Allocation to the ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB-Renderscript and copying the output Allocation to a Bitmap, like in the [android-hdf-viewfinder example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-HdrViewfinder).
Thats what I tried so far:

```
private fun setupRenderscript(){
        rs = RenderScript.create(context)

        val tb1 = Type.Builder(rs, Element.YUV(rs)).setX(size.width).setY(size.height)
        rsInput = Allocation.createTyped(rs, tb1.create(), Allocation.USAGE_IO_INPUT or Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT)

        bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(size.width, size.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val tb2 = Type.Builder(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs)).setX(size.width).setY(size.height)
        rsOutput = Allocation.createTyped(rs, tb2.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT)

        yuvToRgbIntrinistic = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs))
        yuvToRgbIntrinistic.setInput(rsInput)
    }

private fun createCameraPreviewSession() {
        setupRenderscript()

        val texture = cameraTextureView.surfaceTexture //Normal camera preview surface
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(size.width, size.height)
        val surface = Surface(texture)

        captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice?.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
        captureRequestBuilder?.addTarget(surface)
        captureRequestBuilder?.addTarget(rsInput.surface) //Attach Allocation Surface to CaptureRequest
        cameraDevice?.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, rsInput.surface), cameraCaptureSession, backgroundHandler)

private val surfaceTextureListener = object : SurfaceTextureListener {
        override fun onSurfaceTextureAvailable(texture: SurfaceTexture?, width: Int, height: Int) {
            openCamera(width, height)
        }

        override fun onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(texture: SurfaceTexture?, width: Int, heigth: Int) {
            configureTransform(width, heigth)
        }

        override fun onSurfaceTextureUpdated(texture: SurfaceTexture?){
            if (::rsOutput.isInitialized){
                log("Image")
                rsInput.ioReceive()
                yuvToRgbIntrinistic.forEach(rsOutput)
                rsOutput.copyTo(bmOut)
            }
        }

        override fun onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(texture: SurfaceTexture?) = true
    }
```

The camera preview works fine and now fatal errors are thrown but I don't get the preview as a bitmap. I get the following log messages:
For `rsInput.ioReceive()`:

```
E/NdkImageReader: acquireImageLocked: Output buffer format: 0x22, ImageReader configured format: 0x1
E/RenderScript: lockNextBuffer: acquire image from reader 0x7427c7d8a0 failed! ret: -10000, img 0x0
E/RenderScript_jni: non fatal RS error, Error receiving IO input buffer.
```

For `yuvToRgbIntrinistic.forEach(rsOutput)` I get the same message multiple times, probably for every pixel:

```
E/RenderScript: YuvToRGB executed without data, skipping
```

So it seems something is not working with copying/reading the data into the input Allocation, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. It should work similar to the hdr example linked above.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that attaching an ImageReader to the camera reduces the framerate drastically (not any image conversion, but just using the ImageReader without any additional code)

That shouldn't be happening. You might not have properly configured the output targets of your camera session and the image reader. You also need to make sure that you close the images sent to the image reader as quickly as possible, so the next one can come in. If you really care about performance, you should be using YUV_420_888 as the pixel format and, depending on the size of the output target, 3-5 frames as a buffer for the image reader. Here's some sample code to help you get started adapted from [this blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-android-camera-capture-sessions-and-requests-4e54d9150295):

```
val bufferSize = 3
val imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(
    // Pick width and height from supported camera output sizes
    width, height, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, bufferSize)

// Retrieve surface from image reader
val imReaderSurface = imageReader.surface
val targets: MutableList<Surface> = arrayOf(imReaderSurface).toMutableList()

// Create a capture session using the predefined targets
cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(targets, object: CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
    override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
        // Submit capture requests here
    }
    // Omitting for brevity...
    override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) = Unit
}, null)
```

Regarding the RenderScript error, it's a bit hard to tell what's going on with the details you provided. I would recommend using the [RenderScript support library](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute#ide-setup), if you are not doing that already, and test your code in an emulator to rule out potential driver implementation issues.